# Paypal Sandbox suddenly stopped sending IPNs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Paypal Sandbox stopped sending IPN without any apparent reason. It was working yesterday but when I came back today it stopped sending IPN. I have not changed my application code at all in between. Can anyone tell me the reason why it stopped working??

Comment: BTW, if you want to get more help - change/add PayPal tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a specialist in PayPal but as far as I know, if IPN notification from PayPal fails for a 3 times - it will be disabled. You should go to your SandBox settings and enable it again.